# ReSharper C# Intellisense Show Overridable Members After Typing Override Keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, resharper-2018

I was recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 / ReSharper 2017.1 to Visual Studio 2017 / ReSharper 2018.3 when the IT department recently had to re-image my work machine and installed updated versions of all the software I use. I've noticed a strange behavior with a feature that I use frequently.

```
public class Foo { }
public class Bar { }

public class Parent
{
    protected virtual void DoThing1() { }
    protected virtual void DoThing2() { }
    protected virtual void DoThing3(Func<Foo, Bar> callback)
    {
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        DoThing3( /* ReSharper Intellisense here ... */ );
    }

    override /* ReSharper Intellisense here... */
}
```

While working in classes with overridable members, such as in the `Child` class illustrated above, I usually type `override` and the Intellisense menu shows me a targeted suggestion list, prioritizing the overridable members for the type at the top of the list.

Here ReSharper suggests a targeted list of overridable members.

[image: ReSharper suggests overridable Members while in Visual Studio Mode]

After upgrading to ReSharper 2018.3, however, the Intellisense menu now shows me a general list containing any and everything it can think of, starting with a list of keywords.

Here ReSharper suggests everything. See the scrollbar on the side?

[image: ReSharper suggests anything it can think of]

I have found several ways to work around this problem, but they all break other features that I also use heavily.

#### Attempt 1

If I go to `ReSharper > Options > Environment > IntelliSense > General` and select the `Visual Studio` option, this issue is fixed. However, this breaks the way Intellisense suggests signatures for Lambda expressions.

Here ReSharper suggests some options for the Lamda Expression (ReSharper Intellisense).

[image: ReSharper suggests a few options for fulfilling the Lambda Expression]

Here ReSharper provides no options for the Lambda Expression (Visual Studio Intellisense).

[image: ReSharper suggests general options, none specific to the Lambda Expression]

#### Attempt 2

If I leave ReSharper Intellisense enabled (through the process described in Attempt 1) and instead go to `ReSharper > Options > Environment > IntellSense > Completion Filters` and select the `Persist filters state` option and select `Exclude` for `Keywords` under the `C#` sub tab, this also fixes the override keyword problem as well as the Lambda Expression problem, but introduces another issue... I now have no Intellisense for keywords lol.

Here, the Intellisense menu suggests no keywords, because they are disabled.

[image: Who needs keywords anyway]

### Question

Does anybody know of a way to enable overridable Member suggestions, Lambda Expression suggestions, and keyword suggestions as described above within Visual Studio 2017 / ReSharper 2018.3?

Comment: I've noticed this problem. I don't know if it's a bug - or just JetBrains tweaking the way intellisense works. I've switched to skipping the 'override' keyword, and just start typing the name of the method I want to override ... it seems to pick it up then. But it's not exactly a fix..

Comment: I often have the problem where I know there's a method I want to override, but forget its name, so I'll just type override to get things started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an ticket filed for this on JetBrains' issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469670

Maybe if they see that there are annoyed users then the fix comes sooner.

Comment: I didn't even think to check to see if it was a bug. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to first write override and then delete the last one or two letters and then ReSharper starts suggesting the overridable methods.